# Named route always returns true even if it doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

What I'm trying to do is return the "post type" based on the named route. I do not want to use a route param like this `Route::get('/{post-type}');`.

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('/category/{category}')->group(function () { 
    Route::get('/article','PostController@topPostType')->name('articlePostType');

    //Route::get('/video','PostController@topPostType')->name('videoPostType');
});
```

**PostController**

```
public function topPostType(Category $category, Request $request)
{
    return $this->getPostType($request);
}

protected function getPostType(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->route()->name('videoPostType')) {
        return 'video';
    } elseif ($request->route()->name('articlePostType')) {
        return 'article';
    } else{
        return 'Not working';
    }
}
```

In the PostController the `getPostType()` method is suppose to return a string of the post type based on what the route name is. The problem is even if I comment out the videoPostType named route or use the articlePostType named route I still return "video" in the `getPostType()` method.

Comment: try `dd($request->route()->getName())` to check what is the name of the route first. and make sure you name your route as well or else it will return null

Comment: I'm getting the appropriate route names. So the video route  is the "videoPostType" and the article route is "articlePostType". `$request->route()->getName() === "videoPostType"` works just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `named()` not `name()`

```
if ($request->route()->named('profile')) {
    //
}
```